# Graph theory question about planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How can i prove that every planar graph can be expressed as a union of five edge-disjoint forests ?

I think I should use theorem that says : ' Every planar graph contains vertex with degree 5 or less' and maybe continue similalry to five color theorem, but I am not sure.

Any hints are welcomed.

Thanks for help.

EDIT
I narrowed it to this :

We know that every planar graph contains vertex of degree <=5. If we pull of this vertex with its adjacent edges, we will get a smaller graph with maximum of 5 edges, which we can easily distribute into 5 forests(or color into 5 different colors for easier imagination). We just repeat the process until we color the whole graph. Now we need to prove that there won't be any cyrcles in forests(triangles(or bigger) with all edges of the same color). I think it should be done by contradiction. If we assume that there is a cyrcle in one of the forests, there should be something that contradicts the algorithm. (When I tried some examples on paper, I found out that there were cases where 2/3 of a triangle was the same color, but never a full cyrcle.)
If you could tell me how to finish this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: can we assume it is finite?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, "Every planar graph contains vertex with degree 5 or less". I think you can use this together with induction on the number of vertices to get what you want: pull off the vertex of degree <= 5 and see what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still cant figure it out. Here are my thoughts... If we have vertex(v) of degree <= 4, vertex v with its edges could be forest 1 and other 4 vertices with edges would be other 4 forests (so there wouldnt be any cycles). Is this correct? In case of 5 lets say that we have a vertex(v) of degree 5. We pull the vertex(v), now we are left with 5 vertices of degree n - 1. If they (with edges) would represent 5 different forests then there shouldnt be cycles, but what about vertex(v) ? Should it be part of one of the forests? How do I prove that there wont be any cycles?

Comment: @Lemonicious If you're doing it by induction, what can you say about $G-v$?

Comment: If G can be expressed as a union of 5 edge-disjoint forests then   G - v can too... or did u mean that if I have vertex(v) of <5 degree then I pull of the v (G - v) and "put" the remaining vertices into forests(1,2,3,4,5). Now I should have 1 empty forest where would I "put" the vertex v with edges.

Comment: @Lemonicious You don't really want to say "If G can be expressed as a union of 5 edge-disjoint forests then G - v can too", although that's true: after all, what we're trying to *show* is that $G$ can be expressed as a union of 5 edge-disjoint forests. Your second statement is closer: if we're using induction, our induction hypothesis tells us that $G-v$ can be expressed as a union of 5 edge-disjoint forests. Now we just need to figure out what to do with the 5 edges incident to $v$. Seems like we should try to fit them into the existing forests somehow.